# What does ぐてっと mean?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I saw it in the following context:

> xxは、ぐてっと俺に体を預け、胸に顔を埋めてくる

Based on the spelling, I wonder if it's similar to [ぐでんぐでん](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%90%E3%81%A7%E3%81%90%E3%81%A7/), but I'm not sure about that. Based on context, I'm guessing it means something like to collapse (out of exhaustion/tiredness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ぐてっと」 roughly means "in a lazy or lethargic  manner", "lacking energy", "lifelessly", etc.　「ぐ**た**っと」 and 「ぐたりと」 virtually mean the same thing. Just think of Gudetama and you will get the picture.

So, this person kind of leaned against another in such a manner.

「ぐでんぐでん」 is quite different as it means "in a highly intoxicated manner".

「ぐてっと」, all by itself, does not suggest any alcohol consumption.